# Magento - Remove Filter while Reset Filter is selected

Tags: magento

I have been searching solution for this where I have a filter on the collection on Admin grid. We achieve that by doing

> $collection->addFieldToFilter('field',value);

When I do this, I could very well see the filtered collection on grid. But what I would like to see is, when I click on "Reset Filter" on the page, I want the filter I set above to disappear and display All.

Is it possible? Appreciate any hint/solution!

Comment: Any Magento collection can be filtered using "addFieldToFilter". You should look into some instruction on how to create admin grid in Magento, since it is not that simple as just filtering collection. For example: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/

Comment: I am sorry but I think you didn't get my question right. I already know how to do addFieldToFilter. But the question is to how to **remove** it when I click Reset on the grid page.

Answer (score 0):

When you clicked "Reset Filter", you can send a request to the same controller action with some param. And the return data could be `$this->getCollection()`, without any filters applied. Then you will get all the data.